# eclipse not responding and showing error in log

Tags: eclipse

I have not made any changes in configs but still when i am trying to open my eclipse today it is not responding despinte many attempts. In the logs i can see the error -

> !MESSAGE While loading class
>   "org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationListener", thread
>   "Thread[Worker-5,5,main]" timed out waiting (5000ms) for thread
>   "Thread[org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler,1,main]" to
>   finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.1.v20111129-2031
>   [205]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-5,5,main]" is
>   proceeding but "org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationListener"
>   may not be fully initialized. !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for
>   bundle
>   "reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.1.v20111129-2031.jar"
>   by thread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler".  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)

Answer (score 0):

> this problem occurs 
>   if there are unsaved changes and you close eclipse forcefully.

Simple Solution :

Go to your workspace folder inside `\.metadata\.plugins` 
**remove\delete** the contents of `.plugins`

> Warning !!!!! after restarting your workspace will reset all the
>   changes will be lost

**if you want to restore the old workspace below are the steps**

```
1.File 
2.Import
  2.1 General: Select Existing projects into workspace  
  2.2 Select root directory: 
  2.3 Browse to old workspace folder (the SAME with the current workspace folder is OK)
```